# Why is my Script taking so long to execute and how can I fix or get around it?

Tags: google-apps-script

My code is hitting the maximum exceeded time for google app scripts and I'm not sure why. Previously this code would run in maybe a minute or two, and now with no changes it only just gets over half way through the data I want. Is there a way to optimise this so it takes a shorter amount of time or a way I can save the team and I variables to run the script a second time from where it finished?

````
  {
    for(var team in response.returnData.equipos) 
    {
      if(response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length > 0) 
      {
        var i = 0;
        while(i < response.returnData.equipos[team].members.length)
        {
          sheetName.appendRow([response.returnData.equipos[team].name, response.returnData.equipos[team].members[i].userId]);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  if(team.length > 0) 
  {
    sheetName.getRange('D2').setValue('=NOW()');
    sheetName.getRange('D1').setValue(sheetName.getRange('D2').getValue());
    sheetName.getRange('D2').clear();
  }```
````

Comment: What's the point of the `if` block at then end? Are you just trying to get the current date? Why not use javascript's `new Date()`?

Comment: The last if statement is something I took from another project as a stamp to say whhen the code was executed. I'm still new to app script but i'll give new Date a try.

Comment: This isn't so much apps-script as just plain javascript. You might want to look into [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and maybe a couple of tutorials on YouTube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your script is slow is that on every loop you are doing an `appendRow()`, which is an API call, which is slow. You need to refer to the [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) document for guidance.

Now to your problem.

Judging from your code, your source data looks like something like this:

```js
const response = {
  returnData: {
    equipos: [
      { name: 'team 1', members: [{ userId: 1 }, { userId: 2 }] },
      { name: 'team 2', members: [{ userId: 3 }, { userId: 4 }] },
      { name: 'team 3', members: [{ userId: 5 }, { userId: 6 }] },
    ],
  },
};
```

And the outcome you are looking for to append to our sheet looks  like this:

```js
[ [ 'team 1', 1 ], 
  [ 'team 1', 2 ], 
  [ 'team 2', 3 ], 
  [ 'team 2', 4 ], 
  [ 'team 3', 5 ], 
  [ 'team 3', 6 ] ]
```

In order to avoid doing an `appendRow()` on every loop, you need to build up a 2D array that looks like the output above and then add it all with one API call.

To build the output in question, you need to run this code:

```js
const output = response.returnData.equipos.reduce(
  (acc, team) => [
    ...acc,
    ...team.members.map(member => [team.name, member.userId]),
  ],
  []
);
```

Now that you have that data in the correct format, append this to your sheet like so (this is supposing that `sheetName` from your code is an actual spreadsheet object and not just its name as the variable name suggests):

```js
const lRow = sheetName.getLastRow();
sheetName
  .getRange(lRow + 1, 1, output.length, output[0].length)
  .setValues(output);
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @MattOlliff Please do [accept my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) if it did help :)